# Angularjs app and Webpack 5 results in ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am struggling with building the AngularJS app after upgrading to Webpack 5.
Even we do shim with the following lines in webpack config, it doesn't help us anymore.

```
config.resolve.alias['angular$'] = __dirname + '/node_modules/angular/angular';
config.module.rules.push({
        test: /angular\.js$/,
        use: 'exports-loader?window.angular'
    });
```

Previous webpack versions supported that properly for us. The build ends with the following two errors.

Can anybody help, please?

```
Error  in ./node_modules/angular-ui-router/lib-esm/angular.js

Module build failed (from ../node_modules/angular/index.js): ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/angular/angular.js:36598:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/angular/index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)

 error  in ./node_modules/angular/angular.js

Module build failed (from ../node_modules/angular/index.js): ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/angular/angular.js:36598:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/node_modules/angular/index.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used webpack with an angular project, but try to add a `node` entry to your webpack config:

```js
  node: {
    global: true,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
  },
```